# Why is my object being duplicated when I try to add it to an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, object

I'm using the following to loop through some returned SQL data that has two fields.

```
cont = []
datarow = {}

for x in result:
    input = x[0]
    response = x[1]

    datarow['input'] = input
    datarow['response'] = response
    print(datarow)
    cont.append(datarow)
```

The result is

```
{'input': 'do you have a pet?', 'response': 'yes, I have a dog'}
[{'input': 'do you have a pet?', 'response': 'yes, I have a dog'}]
{'input': "What is your dog's name?", 'response': 'Ringo'}
[{'input': "What is your dog's name?", 'response': 'Ringo'}, {'input': "What is your dog's name?", 'response': 'Ringo'}]
```

The eventual format is correct, but the data is not. I was expecting to have an array with two objects in it, the two questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the for loop runs, you assign the new item to the `datarow` dictionary and the whole `datarow` to the `cont` list. It would be best if you did something like:

```py
cont = []

for x in result:
  datarow = {}
  myInput = x[0]
  response = x[1]
  
  datarow['input'] = myInput
  datarow['response'] = response
  cont.append(datarow)
```

A side note: never use a name that previously has been assigned to an in-built function in python. `input` is a function that takes input from the user through the console. I have changed its name to `myInput` in order to avoid any misunderstanding.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!